# GAGA, positive line bundles, Kodaira embedding, and homogeneous coordinate rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds, ample-bundles, gaga

Let $M$ be a compact K"ahler manifold and let $L$ be a positive line bundle over $M$. We know from the Kodaira embedding theorem that from $L^{\otimes k}$ for some $k$ we can construct an embedding $\iota$ of $M$ into complex projective space.

I have heard it said that the homogeneous coordinate ring of the image of $\iota$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of the holomorphic sections of $L^{\otimes k}$ for $k \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Why is this so and where can I find a proof? I guess this is part of the great GAGA dictionary . . .

Comment: This is not true. First of all, to get an embedding, you need to take some power of $L$. Once you have done that, you need the homomorphisms $\operatorname{Sym}^kH^0(L)\rightarrow H^0(L^k) $ to be surjective for all $k$ — in general, this will hold only after taking again some power of $L$.

Comment: @abx: That's what I meant when I wrote "from $L$ we can construct an embedding" . . .  since the tensor power of $L$ is constructed from $L$ :) But sure perhaps this is not clear. I will edit.

Comment: @abx: Can you suggest a reference for why this holds, or is it "obvious" from Kodaira embedding?

Comment: By definition, the homogeneous coordinate ring is the image of the homomorphism $h:\bigoplus \operatorname{Sym}^k H^{0}(L)\rightarrow\bigoplus H^0(L^k) $, so it is equal to the right hand term if and only if $h$ is surjective — this is called *projective normality* of $L$. Now  $h^k$ is surjective for $k$ large enough — this follows from an old theorem of Serre.

Comment: @abx: Thanks again for the explanation. For me (coming from algebraic geometry) the homogeneous coordinate coordinate ring of $V \subseteq \mathbb{P}^n$ is a quotient of the polynomial algebra $\mathbb{C}[X_1, \dots, X_N]$ by the homogeneous ideal defining $V$. I guess what I am asking is how this definition relates to the definition you have given above.

Comment: If $L$ embeds $M$ into $\mathbb{P}^n$,  $\ \bigoplus \operatorname{Sym}^k H^0(L)=$ $\mathbb{C}[x_0,\ldots ,x_n]$, and the kernel of $h$ is the homogeneous ideal of $M$, so $\operatorname{Im} h $ is the  homogeneous coordinate ring of $M$.

Comment: @abx: Ok, now I (finally) get it. Thanks a lot for the explanation. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.